# puppet ruby gem nullpo segfault

Tags: linux, postgresql, rubygems, puppet

Why the pg gem is crash when call it inside of puppet environment but not when are called in the pure environment ? What I've missed ?

- Server: Ubuntu 18.04 latest
- Puppet 5.5 masterless
- postgres 10

```
$ /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/gem install pg
```

> Fetching: pg-1.1.4.gem (100%)
>   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   Successfully installed pg-1.1.4
>   Parsing documentation for pg-1.1.4
>   Installing ri documentation for pg-1.1.4
>   Done installing documentation for pg after 0 seconds
>   1 gem installed

```
$ run-puppet
```

> /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56: [BUG] Segmentation fault at > 0x0000000000000000
>   ruby 2.4.9p362 (2019-10-02 revision 67824) [x86_64-linux]

Similiar code snippet what actually test connection between ruby env and host services:

```
require ('pg')

conn = PG.connect( dbname: "puppetdb", password: 'password2' , host: 'localhost',  user: 'user2' )
conn.close()
```

```
#
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:lookup_ssl) do
    begin
        require ('pg')
    rescue LoadError
        raise Puppet::DataBinding::LookupError, "Error loading pq gem library."
    end

    dispatch :up do
        param 'Hash', :options
        param 'Hash', :search
    end

    def up(options, search)
        data = [] # 
        conn = PG.connect( dbname: options['database'], password: options['password'], host: options['host'],  user: options['user'] )
        conn.close()
        return data

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend has this issue and he resolved by using Postgres 9.6, reinstall pg by using cmd:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=POSTGRES_PATH/9.6/bin/pg_config
```